# How to generate BOM for Gradle buildscript dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies

My team is building software in a heavily-regulated environment, so we need a complete Bill of Materials--even for our build tools themselves.  We are currently using Gradle 2.12, but can upgrade if it solves our current problem.

I'm trying to generate a BOM for Gradle; a list of all the buildscript dependencies.  We can already generate one for the code we're building; this is just the set of dependencies that Gradle itself needs.  Currently, we are using the following task to get a list of buildscript dependencies:

```
    task buildscriptDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {
        configurations = [buildscript.configurations.classpath]
    }
```

However, this only gives us direct dependencies, not the transitive ones.

The ultimate test is to use this BOM to populate a local artifact repository (Artifactory, if it matters) and build based on that, completely disconnected from the internet.  If we can't build without the internet, we can't pass audit.

Does anybody know of a way to generate a complete buildscript BOM?

EDIT: I've found something out in the last couple of days which makes this problem harder than originally thought: the list of dependencies is a part of the BOM, not the entire thing.

POM files can list dependencies, but they can also list parents.  I don't have deep knowledge of POM parents, but what I can see so far is:

- If foo version 209 declares 'foo-parent' as a parent, you're going to need foo-parent version 209.
- In such a case, foo is said to inherit from foo-parent, similar to how classes can inherit from each other.

The standard ways to auto-generate dependency files don't list parents.  Therefore, I'm not getting the full BOM.  Since I'm using the BOM to preload a repository, all my builds are failing because various dependencies can't find their mommies.

Comment: Isn't gradle's `DependencyReportTask` what you're looking for?

Comment: Or maybe `gradle dependencies --configuration compile` ?

Comment: What dependencies are you seeing printed / how do you know they are missing transitives?

Comment: The more I look, the less I think that I'm missing transitives and the more I think I'm missing parents.

Comment: so the "current way" you listed doesn't work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gradle 2.12, you can use the built-in task `gradle buildEnvironment` to print a tree of all your buildscript dependencies including transitives.

Answer (score 1):

```
In gradle, we have the option to specify different dependency list in one. 
For ex:

List ruby = ["org.ruby:ruby:2.0.1@jar",
               "commons-cli:commons-cli:1.0@jar",
               "org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.4@jar"]

List hibernate = ['org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5@jar',
                  'somegroup:someorg:1.0@jar']

dependencies {
    runtime ruby, hibernate
}
```